# How to perform the Rosner Test for outliers at the bottom of the distribution?

Tags: r, statistics, data-quality

I am performing a Rosner Outlier Test and want to show the outliers at the bottom of the distribution. I can't see where I could use an argument like `opposite = TRUE` for the Rosner Outlier Test.

Code example for the Rosner Test:

`test <- EnvStats::rosnerTest(df_females$wtval, k = 15)`

Code example for the Grubbs Test:

`test <- outliers::grubbs.test(df_females$wtval, opposite = TRUE)`